# Commutative algebra - integral extensions question

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is homework, but I am pretty stuck and I feel I am lacking intuition on this so I ask.

The question is as follows : let $k$ be a field and $R = k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ (this notation means a polynomial ring in $n$ variables with coefficients in $k$ but there are possibly relations between the variables, i.e. $R \cong k[X_1, \dots, X_n] / I$ where $I$ is an ideal of the ring $k[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ where the elements $X_i$ are algebraically independent indeterminates). Consider $G \le \mathrm{Aut}(R)$ a finite subgroup of automorphisms of the ring and let $R^G$ denote the fixed subring of $R$ by the action of $G$, i.e.
$$
R^G = \{ r \in R \, | \, \forall g \in G, \quad g \cdot r = r\}.
$$
Assume $k \subseteq R^G$. We were asked to show that the extension $R^G \to R$ is an integral extension and that $R$ is a finitely generated $R^G$-module (which is okay). Writing
$$
R = \langle r_1, \dots, r_m \rangle_{R^G},
$$
for each generator $r_i$ we know that there exists an integrality relation of the form
$$
r_i^{n_i} + s_{i1} r^{n_i - 1} + \dots + s_{in_i} = 0, \quad s_{ij} \in R^G.
$$
Fix such a relation for each generator. Define
$$
S = k[ s_{11},\dots,s_{1n_1},s_{21},\dots,s_{2n_2},\dots,s_{mn_m}] \subseteq R^G
$$
to be the $k$-subalgebra generated by the coefficients of these polynomials in $R^G[X]$. We are asked to show that $R$ and $R^G$ are finitely generated $S$-modules and that $R^G$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra (i.e. is a polynomial ring over some elements in $R^G$).

All I have managed to show is that if $R^G$ is a finitely generated $S$-module, then $R$ also is, because since $R$ is a finitely generated $R^G$-module, I can use the fact that 
$$
R = \sum_{i=1}^m R^G r_i = \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{j=1}^p S q_j \right) r_i = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^p r_i q_j.
$$
I don't need a full proof, just a hint towards a solution would be appreciated ; right now I just have no idea where to start.

**Edit:** I asked my teacher and he confirms that all he really wanted was to give steps to show that $R^G$ was an affine $k$-algebra, so we can use whatever generators we want (which wasn't explicit in the question). I'll be fine for the rest, but thank you all for noticing I was doing an impossible question (or uselessly too hard).

Comment: Comments or ideas from someone who does not know a full solution are also okay, the discussion might generate the idea.

Comment: I would try to go the other way. First show that $R$ is a finitely generated $S$-module, and then that $R^G$ is. All this assuming that $r_i$ are really the $x_i$:s, so that we know $R$ to be generated by the $r_i$:s as a $k$-algebra (and hence also as an $S$-algebra).

Comment: I have the same question as Jyrki - do you have the condition that $r_i$ generate $R$ as a $k$-algebra? It seems to be a natural requirement here by your setting. (which also leads to a proof of your question)

Comment: @Sanchez : I guess that in the example I used for my proof the $r_i$'s do generate $R$ as a $k$-algebra because the $x_i$'s are $r_i$'s (but I need more than just the $x_i$'s to get the $R^G$-module). But I don't see how that helps me. And the question doesn't seem to assume the condition you mentioned.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen : I tried both directions, i.e. I tried showing that either $R$ or $R^G$ was finitely generated... all I know is that if I get $R^G$ first then I don't have to work out the second.. but all I know for $R$ is that $S[r_1, \dots, r_n]$ is integral over $S$... I guess that if the $x_i$'s are among the $r_i$'s, that gives me a proof that $R = S[r_1, \dots, r_n]$ is an f.g. $S$-module?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, not sure how you can handle the general case, but you may be interested in a hint if $r_i$ generates $R$ as a $k$-algebra. The map $R$ is at least a finitely generated $S$-algebra, so to show that $R$ is a finitely generated $S$-module, it suffices to show that $S \to R$ is integral. Note that integral closure of $S$ in $R$ is a ring - if we have that extra assumption, can you see how to proceed?

Comment: I don't know who told you to consider $S$ (or better say $r_1,\dots,r_m$) like this, but you are clearly on a wrong track. You don't even know that $S\subset R$ is integral and want to show that it is finite! Definitely $r_1,\dots,r_m$ have to be chosen as being generators of $R$ as a $k$-algebra; then, at least, you can say that $S\subset R$ is integral, but obviously it is even finite and you are almost done.

Comment: @YACP : The homework asks us to consider $S$. I think I will ask my teacher if he wanted us to consider our particular choice of generators for $R$ as an $R^G$-module or if it was meant to be an arbitrary set of generators. I gave it a little thought (after all of your comments) and I think I can figure it out if we get to choose our generators.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I've converted your answer to an edit in response to multiple not-an-answer flags. If you're worried about this question being bumped by the Community user as an unanswered question, I can close it if you'd like.

Comment: @Alex Becker : Whatever, I don't mind.